# Choosing the right eventhandler

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a `treeview` which have as treenodes databases and databases have tables. I want to show listview when I click on the table name. Which eventhandler do I have to use for that? I tried `treenodemouseclick`, `treenodemousedoubleclick` and `mouseclick` handlers, but there was no effect. Please help.

Comment: It would help if you re-worded your question to be clearer.  You mention a ListView and a TreeView as if they are the same, but they are different controls...

Comment: In eventhandler when i clicked on treeview node table, i checked if treenode on which i clicked is table i add to controls new listview (it is for begening) but treenodemouseclick and mouseclick eventhandlers did not do anything, when i clicked on table names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I use AfterSelectEvent which brings a reference to the selected node on the event argument:

```
    private void TvwTraining_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Node.Parent == null)
        {
            // Its a top level node
            ParentObject ParentObj = (ParentObject)e.Node.Tag;
            ShowParentDetails(ParentObj);
        }

        else
        {
            // Its a child node
            ChildObject ChildObj = (ChildObject)e.Node.Tag;
            ShowChildDetails(ChildObj);
        }

    }
```

Then you just need to treat the event depending on the node you get.

Good luck,
Nemesis

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about `Windows.Forms.TreeView`?

If so, and you are dealing with selection of nodes, you want the `BeforeSelect` or `AfterSelect` event.

`BeforeSelect` will let you determine which node is about to be selected and respond accordingly or even cancel the node selection if need be.

`AfterSelect` is best if you aren't trying to do anything specific with node selection, but you want to perform additional work for certain selections (or every selection).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx